# TFS2015 modified Scrum Template Tfs_Warehouse DimWorkItem System_WorkItemType always null

Tags: templates, tfs, tfs-2015, scrum, warehouse

We use a modified Template based on the Scrum template. Basically there are some new fields introduced we are need for our deployment process.

After some time we looked into reporting and take a look in the Tfs_Warehouse database and notices that the Field System_WorkItemType is null all the time.
We can also see this effect on the original Scrum Template which we left in it's original state. Does someone ever had a similar effect.

On our test environment for TFS 2017 we can not reproduce the problem but we are unable to switch to TFS 2017 anytime soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleas try following below steps to fix that:

1. Make sure the field `System.WorkItemType` is in use. For example:

   `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
   witadmin listfields /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC /n:System.WorkItemType`
2. [Manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services
   cube](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube#to-process-the-data-warehouse) to force sync the data.

Check the issue again after the sync.

If that not work, just try to [Rebuild the data warehouse and cube](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/rebuild-data-warehouse-and-cube), then check it again.

If that still not work, just try to create a new team project with the default Scrum template, check if the issue occurs there.

[image]